# How to separately charge two LiPo batteries wired in serial?

Tags: mosfet, battery-charging, safety, switching, lipo

I would like a circuit where 1) two protected LiPo batteries are wired in serial to power the load; and 2) when external power is plugged in the load is disconnected and the batteries are charged separately. I have come up with this circuit:

[image: Two LiPos in serial that are charged separately]

The external power plug is indicated with a switch, and the intention is that connecting the power switches off the two P-channel MOSFETs M1 and M2 to disconnect from the load and then switches on the N-channel MOSFET M3 to connect B2's negative terminal to ground for charging. The chargers would be boards based on a LiPo charger IC such as [MCP73831](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/MCP73831). Each battery would be a [pack of 3 18650's wired in parallel with a protection circuit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/353).

I am concerned that if the FETs switch at different times (for example, if M3 switches on before M1 switches off) that a short circuit could be temporarily created. I'd like to know if this is a possibility, if this circuit has other problems, or if there is a well-known circuit that better solves this problem.

Here is a [falstad simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWKsCcCVgBwoCwIOxiQYDMmATCHiEgpDQKYC0YYAUAG4jkIBs4vej35hymKBJz0S0fBPowEnbn26ZxwlfwVVps+ciUAzECUg4QKfpqtUIYaEnYB3LeFFvR4yG1flyFpj0YDiBCr5uYhqqJCTaEZqxIqGmcVARIRZJ4Cn+Fj4ATjkWYPjJFnkSSq6Z4GXFIEHpAOZu2Ym83ul+MWlmWWk+rv11-CO2habmauIj2cHwcMo4vBXqVKtuOlI0BopsAM4bFQHH4CiUwSBGAIYANgcMESsnFi9bbABepgiUJOTSTBZAHccAAOQIrAicz6v1S8Vc72y7yi6RMIwB0WskHEOHsjnACVUpWsxIu3Uip00miGUwqOLpM3SRTIJTEdhE7IU0HYLKBbjxpO0yBcnnZJDhXgp1JicJpbBMOCalV+GlO-3ABNFIxJjMxFJ19UFo3S31Z4HFkvZlDAEMI7DN-MSctUNrtUMRYBERq9H093v4xqltJwGt1oXEupDm3DMfJtNV8LO8yJIkENHZXvCrkTWYzGgZIeVpyVwXqRbLgZj5YiiYC9Dr+EutfF00TKZz1qb+cZCcz6b4wXTfdmaUHSYT6bz4-1k6EO3HKaOM4X6dn4Gu90eCVOUs0wcO3FOxZKHiutweTz8u+tu7PqZNlSjD+pVNUPiOT-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-aGH8wLgrucyEAANTCiL2fANqaAsdBKAIBXKCsh27gW5o2dum27rm8zTZs837e6gp5vK073LchgDduoxdee8ybLzg53aK7q3NusXWcNp6O4YXa+7cmy7gAT2RoA) I was using to test switching different FETs at different times. I considered adding a Schottky diode or FET between R1 and the 5V source's negative terminal, but would they introduce a voltage drop that would cause problems with charging B1?

Comment: Good start, welcome!

Comment: [Related Q and A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/598947/is-there-anything-wrong-with-this-mosfet-switching-circuit-that-disconnects-the/598957#598957)

Answer (score 1):

That seems unnecessary. Better to use a single boost regulator to charge the LiPos in series, and use a single FET to disconnect the load.

The technique of *cell balancing* is maybe what you're looking for. Here's an Analog appnote about that: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/active-battery-cell-balancing.html Figure 6, "High efficiency bidirectional balancing" is in the spirit of what you propose I think.

Further reading:

- https://circuitdigest.com/article/cell-balancing-techniques-and-how-to-use-them
- https://www.beyondlogic.org/review-li-ion-lipo-lifepo4-lithium-battery-active-equalizer-balancer-energy-transfer-board/

Related: [Multi-Cell Lithium battery balancing circuit explanation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/397790/multi-cell-lithium-battery-balancing-circuit-explanation)